# Transfering data through FTP to a folder names contain spaces

Tags: file, file-upload, ftp

How to upload into a remote directory through command prompt using FTP.

The directory name is 'TEST DIR'
when i try to connect using command

```
ftp>cd TEST DIR
it is throwing no such directory found error
```

please suggest.

Comment: did u try ls command to list the files...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to enclose your dir with quotes ("), like this:

> cd "TEST DIR"