# Get folders with files from ftp with spaces in their names

Tags: unix, ftp

I am trying to get files from an ftp location. The files are present inside folders in the ftp location and the folder. My folder names contain spaces. For example My folder structure is as below in ftp location:

```
MYFOLDER/Inner folders/inner files***.pdf
MYFOLDER/Second Inner folders/inner files***.pdf
```

My aim is to get all the folders with their files to my local.

I tried `mget -r *` but unable to get the files and got the error "Failed to open file.". Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Seems like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961491/transfering-data-through-ftp-to-a-folder-names-contain-spaces

Comment: Hi I had checked the above link already in it directory name is know but in my case there are multiple directories and name is not known but will definitely come with spaces